# Why does this PHP interface implementation fail?

Tags: php

I've made this simple example to show what i'm trying to do:

```php
<?php

interface UserManagement
{
    public function createUser(object $user): ?string;
}

class User
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $email;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------//

class MyUser extends User
{
}

class MyUserManagement implements UserManagement
{
    public function createUser(MyUser $user): ? string
    {
    }
}
```

This contains an abstract interface definition for user-management and also a base class for a user-object. In the second part it uses that definitions.

When i try to execute the code, the parser bails out:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of MyUserManagement::createUser(MyUser $user): ?string
must be compatible with UserManagement::createUser(object $user): ?string
in ./test.php on line 24
```

I don't understand why it fails, as the definition look pretty equal to me.

Comment: `(object $user)` and `(MyUser $user)`  are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement an interface your functions should have the same type of parameters. In this case the createUser function of interface have (object $user), and the function in your class have (MyUser $user).

Answer (score 0):

That 's the normal behavior in PHP. When you define a method in an interface or in a superclass all inherited classes must implement exactly this signature. You can not override the provided method signature.

Although `MyUser` is of type `object` the signature in your `UserManagement` interface defines the parameter as `object` and not as `MyUser`. Because `MyUserManagement` implements the `UserManagement` interface, the type hint for the `$user` parameter has to be `object`.

It is not possible to override the type hint.

Best practice out there is to define type hints in interfaces or superclasses only. Inherited classed do not need a type hint in that case.